# R: fractionally cointegrated vector autoregressive model with error correction: statistically significant higher returns than cointegration

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration

I can find packages for VECM (vars,urca, tsDyn) but I cannot find:

fractionally cointegrated vector autoregressive model with error correction (FVECM).

There is a package in MATLAB that deals with this: FCVARmodel.m 
Reference: http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/working_papers/papers/qed_wp_1273.pdf

But is there a package (or example) that deals with this in R? 
I have tried:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html

There is also this paper that shows that the fractional cointegration approach yields statistically significant higher returns than the cointegration approach. However it also uses Matlab and not R
http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2614240